# How to get information about a different java process (another JVM instance running different processes) from one JVM process?

Tags: java, memory, process, jvm

I'm writing unit tests to find just how much memory instances of MyClass take up.
I can't seem to do anything about the random chaotic garbage collector that tells me my `MyClass[] myinstances=new MyClass[10000];` takes up negative memory, so i decided to just start up 2 new JVM processes which simply start a class containing a main method, that instantiates a huge arry and hangs.

I know i can start up a new JVM with `Runtime.getRuntime.exec("java my.package.SomeClassWithMainMethod");`

So my question is: how do i get the info about the ammount of memory taken up by the JVM i started?

Thx, you guys rule.

Comment: You are looking for any tool (or) programatically you want to find out memory?

Comment: there is a param passed in to the JVM when you start it; the JVM will take max that much mem that you pass in as that param. These ones: -Xss512k -Xms64m -Xmx512m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [JVisualVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/index.html)  or [JConsole](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html) , they are included in the JDK since 1.6

Answer (score 0):

I think you are better off using a profiler, jvisualvm is probably good enough and comes with your Java distribution. See this question: [How to determine the actual memory usage of a data structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019451/how-to-determine-the-actual-memory-usage-of-a-data-structure)